Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS logs out when iPhone connected for charging
After updating from Ubuntu 22 the issue appeared.
This behavior appears  when I connect nor disconnect the iPhone. And this repeats with usb-C and usb-A cables
On Wayland system just logs out, on X11 I got that very informative message "Oh no! Something has gone wrong"
Here is the log from journalctl right after I plug iPhone in:

сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: [11:08:36.231][3] usbmuxd v1.1.1 starting up
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: [11:08:36.232][3] Successfully dropped privileges to 'usbmux'
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: [11:08:36.232][3] Using libusb 1.0.27
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: libusb: warning [op_get_configuration] device unconfigured
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: libusb: error [op_get_active_config_descriptor] device unconfigured
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: [11:08:36.241][3] Could not get old configuration descriptor for device 1-28: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND
сен 27 11:08:36 kernel: ipheth 1-6.1:4.2: ipheth_enable_ncm: usb_control_msg: 0
сен 27 11:08:36 kernel: ipheth 1-6.1:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: [11:08:36.247][3] Initialization complete
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: [11:08:36.247][3] Enabled exit on SIGUSR1 if no devices are attached. Start a new instance with "--exit" to trigger.
сен 27 11:08:36 NetworkManager[1545]:   [1727424516.2478] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/22)
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: [11:08:36.248][3] Connecting to new device on location 0x1001c as ID 1
сен 27 11:08:36 usbmuxd[28065]: [11:08:36.248][3] Connected to v2.0 device 1 on location 0x1001c with serial number 00008030-0003446422C3402E
сен 27 11:08:36 kernel: ipheth 1-6.1:4.2 enx52f4eb79e95a: renamed from eth0
сен 27 11:08:36 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 33 callbacks suppressed
сен 27 11:08:36 kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1727424516.251:610): pid=1462 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="DeviceAdded" name=":1.14"s
сен 27 11:08:36 colord[2532]: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
сен 27 11:08:36 colord[2532]: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
сен 27 11:08:36 NetworkManager[1545]:   [1727424516.2666] device (eth0): interface index 21 renamed iface from 'eth0' to 'enx52f4eb79e95a'
сен 27 11:08:36 NetworkManager[1545]:   [1727424516.2719] device (enx52f4eb79e95a): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
сен 27 11:08:36 NetworkManager[1545]:   [1727424516.2751] settings: (enx52f4eb79e95a): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 2'
сен 27 11:08:36 colord-sane[28062]: io/hpmud/musb.c 2102: Invalid usb_open: Permission denied
сен 27 11:08:40 ModemManager[1691]:  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6.1': not supported by any plugin
сен 27 11:08:46 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727424526.867:612): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/run/systemd/resolve/io.systemd.Resolve" pid=2930 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=134 ouid=101
сен 27 11:08:46 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727424526.867:613): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/run/systemd/resolve/io.systemd.Resolve" pid=2930 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=134 ouid=101
сен 27 11:08:46 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727424526.870:614): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/run/systemd/resolve/io.systemd.Resolve" pid=2930 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=134 ouid=101
сен 27 11:08:46 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727424526.873:615): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" class="file" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/run/systemd/resolve/io.systemd.Resolve" pid=2930 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=134 ouid=101

I checked this and this answers related to this error but solutions did not help
I guess clean install may fix the problem, but I'm unable to reinstall OS at this moment.
Maybe there are other solutions?
Thanks in advance.
